# Line chart with Apache POI - error

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

I am creating line chart using apache poi however during compilation there is NoClassDefFoundError.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("line chart");

Drawing<?> drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
((XSSFChart)chart).setTitleText("This is my title");

ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);

ChartDataSource<Integer> test = DataSources.fromArray(new Integer[]{2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017});
ChartDataSource<Integer> test2 = DataSources.fromArray(new Integer[]{4805, 7351, 5333, 7183, 6230, 4050, 6963});

LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();
data.addSeries(test, test2);

chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
workbook.write(outputStream);
```

I found that the problem is with ChartAxis and ValueAxis but I do not know what's wrong and how to fix it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTCatAx
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.impl.CTPlotAreaImpl.addNewCatAx(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.charts.XSSFCategoryAxis.createAxis(XSSFCategoryAxis.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.charts.XSSFCategoryAxis.<init>(XSSFCategoryAxis.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart.createCategoryAxis(XSSFChart.java:217)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart.createCategoryAxis(XSSFChart.java:71)
at pl.wasko.cassandrasucker.CassandraSuckerMain.main(CassandraSuckerMain.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTCatAx
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: There is missing dependency. You have [poi-ooxml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.17) and that needs [poi-ooxml-schemas](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.17). See also http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components. Also note http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204. If you have `poi-ooxml`version `3.17`, you also needs `poi-ooxml-schemas` of that version and not having multiple versions in class path.

Comment: In kind of way it helps. There is no error however chart does not exist. There are only couple of values (1000, 2000, 3000 up to 8000) somewhere in the excel file.

Comment: Where are you opening the result `*.xlsx` file? Note, `apache poi` is creating files usable using Microsoft Office. This is tested. Not tested is whether these files also are usable using Libreoffice/OpenOffice or other not Microsoft applications. If that is the problem, please refine your question about this. Please refine the question title also then.